# Change UITextView font size

Tags: ios, swift, fonts, uitextview

I am not able to change the `fontSize` of my `UITextView` even though I set `.isSelectable=false`.

The code below is not working. The `fontSize` is not editable.

```
    let linkLabel: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.text = "Link"
        v.textColor = .lightGray
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext", size: 23)
        v.textAlignment = .right
        v.isSelectable = false
        v.isScrollEnabled = false
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
//        v.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your font size doesn't have any effect because "AvenirNext" doesn't exist.
Try:"AvenirNext-Regular"

```
 let linkLabel: UITextView = {
        let v = UITextView()
        v.backgroundColor = .clear
        v.text = "Link"
        v.textColor = .lightGray
        v.font = UIFont(name: "AvenirNext-Regular", size: 23)
        v.textAlignment = .right
        v.isSelectable = false
        v.isScrollEnabled = false
        v.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100)
//        v.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: "", attributes: [.underlineStyle: NSUnderlineStyle.single.rawValue])
        v.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        return v
    }()
```

This is a good resource to get the correct font names of the fonts included in iOS

http://iosfonts.com